# Unable to attach custom image to AWS Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to attach custom image in SageMaker, it was working fine until I deleted couple of previous version, it started giving me errors as bellow and now I am unable to attach either new image or a new version for existing image.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem have an 400 erroring image & can't add any new images. the 400 erroring image is not listed anywhere in "SageMaker dashboard -> Images", or in "domains->environment" so I can't delete/detach it. Or add any new images. were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after trying everything and getting no helpful info from the aws support other than 'open a support ticket'
I figured it out myself.

(& Yes it is absolutely a bug on the aws side! It is caused by the missing image)

First find your `DomainId`
[image: UI location]
you can find it on the UI or do `aws sagemaker list-domains`

Get your domains current settings:

`aws sagemaker describe-domain --domain-id $DOMAIN_ID`

you will see an output like below.
It will list `CustomImages` associated with that sagemaker domain. & status will likely be in a failed state.

Save your output settings just in case!

(I redacted ids with $$$)

```
    {
        "DomainArn": "arn:aws:sagemaker:$$$",
        "DomainId": "$$$$",
        "DomainName": "$$$",
        ...
        "Status": "Update_Failed",
        ...
        "FailureReason": "ResourceNotFoundError: Image with ARN arn:aws:sagemaker:$$$ does not exist",
        ...
            "KernelGatewayAppSettings": {
                "CustomImages": [
                    {
                        "ImageName": "my_custom_image", # this is the image causing problem, you might have more images listed below
                        "ImageVersionNumber": 1,
                        "AppImageConfigName": "app-image-config-1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

Create a file `update-domain-input.json` update the `CustomImages` list remove the problematic image (but keep others if you have any)

```py
    {
    "DomainId": DOMAIN_ID,
    "DefaultUserSettings": {
        "KernelGatewayAppSettings": {
            "CustomImages": [
                #... add your custom images here (remove the problematic one) 
                # If you have no images you can just pass an empty array then add image from dashboard UI(easier)
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`aws --region ${REGION} sagemaker update-domain --cli-input-json file://update-domain-input.json`

now the error should disappear and you should be able to add any image from the UI.(or If you know the config settings for the image you want to add you can do it during the update-domain step above.)

I pieced together this solution looking at [this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-custom-image-samples/tree/main/examples/rapids-image)

Comment: Thank you :) It was a bug that I faced during my internship. I don't work there anymore, I don't know what happened to it 

Comment: I am getting an error that asks to add AppImageConfig with Image. Do you know where to find AppImageConfig?

Comment: You can pass an empty array for `CustomImages` then add the image from the dashboard `sagemaker dashboard->images`. OR look at the link I provided in the last line search for `aws --region ${REGION} sagemaker create-app-image-config --cli-input-json file://app-image-config-input.json` and modify for your case

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to attach new image versions to SageMaker images before you attach them to the domain. On the left nav under SageMaker dashboard -> Images, you should be seeing a list of images. Create new versions here and you'll then be able to attach these to the domain.

[image: SageMaker console left nav]